# Django: international subroutes

Tags: django, django-urls, django-i18n

It's written in official documentation [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/i18n/translation/#language-prefix-in-url-patterns) that `i18n_patterns()` is only allowed in your root URLconf.

This is a problem for me because I need those URLs working:

- `/en/products/`
- `/fr/produits/`
- `/sv/produkt/`
- `/en/products/detail/[my product name]/`
- `/en/produits/detail/[my product name]/`
- `/sv/produkt/detalj/[my product name]/`
- `/sv/produkt/detalj/[my product name]/`

Heres my root `urls.py`:

```
urlpatterns += i18n_patterns(
    url(_(r'^produits/detail/'),
        include('produits.urls', namespace="produits")
        ),
    url(_(r'^produits/'),
        include('produits.urls', namespace="produits")
        ),
)
```

So, for the lastest translation works ok, but the first one doesn't. The translation is ok, but I want to *transfer the last part (`'detail/'`) to the app `produits`* that should handle it transparently.
How do I do?

Comment: If the URL is in the localised language, why do you need the `/en/` or `/fr/` in there?

Comment: It's automatically prepended in the URLs by `i18n_patterns`

Comment: And why wouldn't it work to just move the `detail/` part to the app's `urls.py`? What have you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I've solved the problem. This is not a good solution but it's the only one working for now with Django 1.8.

I've removed my routes from my "`produits`" application, and added them to the main `urls.py` which means mixing application configuration with global configuration. I dont like it.

I've also added the name of the application before each route: `produits_detail` and `produits_index`. Thus I know the app those routes are for. Once again I dont like mixing "global setting" and specific settings, but it seems I have no choice. Anyway, few lines of code, and it works pretty well.

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.conf.urls.i18n import i18n_patterns
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
from produits import views as p_views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^i18n/', include('django.conf.urls.i18n')),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
]
urlpatterns += i18n_patterns(
    url(_(r'^produits/detail/(?P<slug>[a-zA-Z0-9-_]+)/$'),
        p_views.DetailView.as_view(), name='produits_detail'),
    url(_(r'^produits/'),
        p_views.IndexView.as_view(), name='produits_index'),
)
```